Why is the mass-energy graph for atomic mass $A=98$ not quadratic?
For fixed atomic mass $A$ and varying atomic number $Z,$ the mass of the nucleus is quadratic in $Z$.  Were it possible for $Z$ to vary continuously, we'd have at most one local minimum. Since we are restricting to $Z \in \mathbb{N},$ there is merely at most one local minimum.
So far so good. But just to confirm my thinking, I was looking at mass graphs and noticed something suspicious about the graph mass $A=98$ (see image). The graph says 'relative' instead of absolute, but that's just because the value for the global minimum is subtracted off to make everything look nicer. Adding back this constant, it is impossible for any quadratic to connect these points, much less a cubic. You'd need a polynomial of degree $\ge 4.$
So where's the mistake? I don't doubt the graph and I don't doubt the purely mathematical observations regarding polynomials. I also looked into the citation regarding mass and didn't find any mistakes.

*Citation: Friedlander, G.; Kennedy, J. W.; Miller, J. M. Nuclear and
Radiochemistry, 2nd ed.; John Wiley and Sons: New York, 1964;
Chapter 2.

Well, Technetium is not stable. Being an odd-odd nucleus doesn’t help. So that ‘excess’ mass is reduced binding energy compared with its neighbors.

@JonCuster I don't understand what this has to do with my question.

Jon is explaining why there appears to be an anomaly in the trend of this graph, citing how Tc is unique, specifically how the atoms to either side of Tc are more stable. Is that not what you were asking?

@josephh No. Jon didn't address my question about quadratics. I didn't ask anything about Technetium, I was only asking about the graph (was there a reason I gave off the wrong impression? I'm not trying to be harsh, genuinely curious). Also, if anything the unstability of Technetium is a consequence of this and several similar graphs rather than the other way around; it would be circular logic to explain theory (equations governing graphs) using experiments (observed radioactivity).

I see what you mean. So, the fact that the graph has a small peak at Z=43 is irrelevant to the question?

@josephh Correct. Even if there was no peak at $Z = 43,$ my question would remain the same. For example, if the height at $43$ in the graph was $-9, -99, -999$ etc. for a large valley, or $8, 88, 888$ etc. for a large peak. What should I do to avoid such confusion in the future?

@josephh And just to be extra clear, the question would remain the same because in those cases you still wouldn't be able to fit a quadratic to the graph.

Sure. I'm sorry I misunderstood the context of the question. I'm glad you have a satisfactory answer. Cheers.

Who told you this would be a quadratic?
The famous binding energy expression from the semi-empirical mass formula includes five terms. The volume and surface terms are constant in $Z$. The Coulomb and symmetry terms are quadratic in $Z$. But there is one more term: the pairing term. When $A$ is an even number, this term is not only not quadratic in $Z$, it's non-polynomial in $Z$, being of the form $(-1)^Za_pA^k$. (For odd $A$, the pairing term is zero.)
The effect of the pairing term is highly evident here, with even/even nuclei being more stable than odd/odd nuclei.

Thanks. I checked the cited source again and it says in a footnote that one of the constants actually has a $\pm.$

Worth doing: separate the even-even versus the odd-odd nuclides, fit the two parabolas, and estimate the pairing energy.
